# how to do something right after downloading image using SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

So, I want to show a message to the user right after an image is downloaded and set in ImageView. I am using SDWebImage. how to do that?

Here is my current code

```
    profilePictureImageView.sd_setImage(with: referenceImage, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ImageName.defaultProfilePicture))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
profilePictureImageView.sd_setImage(with: referenceImage, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "cod_logo"), options: [.highPriority]) { (image, error, cashtype, url) in
    if image != nil{
        // Do something Here after load image
    }
    print(error) // Your error is here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `pod 'SDWebImage' = '4.0.0'`  and XCode == 11.3.1

```
self.userAvatar.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: __user_avatar), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "UserDefalutAvatar"), options: .progressiveDownload, progress: { (receivedSize, expectedSize, targetURL) in
       print("The progress value for the downloading is \(receivedSize)")

}) { (downloadedImage, downloadedError, imageCacheType, downloadedURL) in

       if let _downloadedError = downloadedError {
            print("Download image encountered error. \(_downloadedError.localizedDescription)")
            return
       }
       if let _downloadedImage = downloadedImage {
            print("This is downloaded image, you can do it what you want")
       }

}
```